# How many MediaPlayer instances should I create for playing a music collection?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Thinks I've considered so far:

1. Just one for the currently playing song. For the next song a new instance is created every time. Though one also need to call `prepare` and I expect there to be a noticeable gap between the songs.
2. One MediaPlayer instance for every song. There could be more than a hundred songs though and I read that creating too many MediaPlayer instances could lead to problems.
3. I've tried to implement some logic to have a MediaPlayer instance for the currently playing song as well as the next and the previous (three in total). This turns out to be a lot more complicated than I expected.

Since I'm hardly to first person to implement a music player for Android, I'd like to ask, is there a generally recommended approach for how to do this?

Comment: Try `ExoPlayer`: https://youtu.be/XfadYTxKK3s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple MediaPlayers is not a good Idea. MediaPlayers are really a pain to deal with. Once one MediaPlayer gets out of your sight (you lose the reference to it ) it keeps playing music and the only way to kill it is by killing the whole App. This is a very bad user experience. The generally recommended way is to play all of the collection with one MediaPlayer; and after the track is finished or when you want to skip to the next song then you just call:

```
mediaPlayer.stop() 
mediaPlayer.reset()
mediaPlayer.create()
```

Calling this sequence will clear the MediaPlayer from old data and give it the new data and will avoid problems like having two MediaPlayers playing on top of each other.

If you want the music to play in the background you are going to need to use a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) and place the MediaPlayer in it.